# Jackson JSON serialization mapping

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have two java classes A and B that I would like to be able to serialize to JSON such that their content looks the same to a consumer.

I ommitted the constructors/getters/setters to keep it minimal.

```
public class A {

    @JsonProperty("b")
    private B b;

}

public class B {

   @JsonProperty("propertyB")
   public String propertyB;

}
```

When I serialize A I get

```
{
   b: {
       propertyB: ''
   }
}
```

But I want it to look like B's serialization:

```
{
  propertyB: ''
}
```

Is there any way to achieve that simply by configuring the serialization process respectively, i.e. using jackson annotations or some other form of jackson configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonUnwrapped`

```
public class A {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private B b;
}
```

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html